# I2C slave NACK issue in 3.3 V level to 1.8 V

Tags: i2c

We are using an I2C slave U67 (1.8 V) in our design and a U59 level translator is used to match the voltage range from the HOST processor (3.3 V). We are facing an issue during the communication.

1. Non-working case: I2C detecting, but communication is not happening (found NAC from slave); refer to attached image.
   The salve address is 0x20
   [image]

[image]

Please let me know what could be the issue.

Comment: Is it possible the slave is holding the SCL down? In the case of clockstretching that would be possible. SDA and SCL seem to react normally in high/low and start.

Comment: What's the slave address? Also, U67 and U59 sound like PCB designators, meaning that they literally mean any chip at all. Please, specify what your I2C slave device is and what the level translator is called.

Comment: It could be anything. There is not enough info to even start guessing.

Comment: sorry attachment was missed, Uploaded schematic & I2C address,

Comment: A common confusion: I2C address may be 7-bit, but you specify it as 8-bit (0x20). So the confusion is between (0x40) and (0x20). The 8-bit value on your bus timing is (0x40). Try (0x20) instead, and see if you get a ACK.